# Why is ajax call not being hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This function used to hit on page load now the first alert displays but the one inside of the ajax call does not. This doenst seem to hit the ajax call at all.  It is supposed to call a method inmy controller but no longer seems to hit it.

```
 $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert("2");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'CallCenter/CallCenterAmt',
                type: 'Post',
                contentType: 'application/json;',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    if (data == 2) {
                        document.getElementById("First").style.display = 'Inline';
                        document.getElementById("Second").style.display = "Inline";
                        document.getElementById("Third").style.visibility = "Hidden";
                    }
                    else if (data == 3) {
                        document.getElementById("First").style.display = 'Inline';
                        document.getElementById("Second").style.display = 'Inline';
                        document.getElementById("Third").style.display = 'Inline';
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("First").style.display = 'Inline';
                        document.getElementById("Second").style.display = 'None';
                        document.getElementById("Third").style.display = 'None';
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Could be that the ajax call is unseccessful.  Can you see what is going on using some sort of web developer tool (F12 in many browsers)

Comment: Add `error : function() { console.log(argements)}`

Comment: Just like you have a success handler, you need an error handler to cover all of your bases.

Comment: You do not need both `$(function () {});` **and** `$(document).ready(function () {});` nested - they do the same thing, so they're redundant. (that wouldn't fix anything, I'm just pointing it out)

Comment: Which of the alerts do you get? And I can't see where a controller would be called anywhere

Comment: Also remove `;` after this `contentType: 'application/json;',`

Comment: posted code into to fiddle, and seems to work just fine, other than returning a 404 for the URL in the fiddle (no surprise).

Comment: `type: 'Post',` should be `type: 'POST',` but I wouldn't have thought that would cause an error.

Comment: You don't seem to be passing your `POST` any data, does CallCenterAmt not need any?

Comment: @epascarello seems like that typo will cause its own issues ;-)

Comment: @Mathletics Well hopefully the OP can spell arguments better than me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
$(function () {
    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        url: 'CallCenter/CallCenterAmt',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json' // don't need semicolon within quotes
    });
    ajaxRequest.done(function(data){
        alert('done');
        var firstDisplay = document.getElementById("First").style.display;
        var secondDisplay = document.getElementById("Second").style.display;
        var thirdDisplay = document.getElementById("Third").style.visibility;
        if (data == 2) {
            firstDisplay = 'Inline';
            secondDisplay = "Inline";
            thirdDisplay = "Hidden";
        } else if (data == 3) {
            firstDisplay = 'Inline';
            secondDisplay = 'Inline';
            thirdDisplay = 'Inline';
        } else {
            firstDisplay = 'Inline';
            secondDisplay = 'None';
            thirdDisplay = 'None';
        }
    });
    ajaxRequest.fail(function(){
        alert('fail');
    });
});

window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
    var errorText = 'message: ' + errorMessage + '\nurl: ' + url + '\nline: ' + line;
    alert(errorText);
}
```